# Scraping with Selenium Web Driver cant find Element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape an element from a page using Selenium Web Driver and I cant seem to figure out how to grab a certain text. I am trying to get the sting " 35330100: Oil and gas drilling rigs and equipment" in this line of code below.

```
<td class="tRight altRow">35330100: Oil and gas drilling rigs and equipment</td>
```

the syntax that I used in my notebook which is throwing me an error is as below

```
primary = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tRight altRow")
```

Any help would be helpful.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that the blank space in the `class` attribute separates different class names, so you should search for either `tRight` or `altRow`, but not both.

Comment: It definitely does not work :(

Answer (score -1):

Afaik there is no method called `find_element_by_class_name` available thru selenium webdriver. Use something like this:

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('.tRight.altRow'));`

Edit: Didn't notice the OP's question was about Python. Here's the edit - 
`driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tRight.altRow')`

Comment: No. There is a method called `find_element_by_class_name`. That's not an issue. Also note that your syntax is definitely not a Python

Comment: @Andersson Oh never mind, I thought OP was using the Java version. You can try doing it with CSS Selectors instead... it should look something like -
`driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tRight.altRow')`